# Web Services with SQLite

Tags: android, json, web-services

I am developing an android dashboard app to display various charts. 
I am having a local SQLLitedatabase in my application which contains all the values to be displayed.

But I want that whenever my app loads my db should get refreshed by hitting a web server if data connection is ON or else it should display the charts with the local db in offline mode.

Can I update my db using the JSON parser provided by the Android API?
Please suggest the best protocol for this

Comment: why not just update your db after fetching data from JSON parser?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. For network related queries you can use the Volley library. That will be good try that one.

[clicke here](https://github.com/ogrebgr/android_volley_examples) for Tutorial how to use the Volley.